# dbms_lock.sleep not working when it encounters the code

Tags: oracle, plsql, delay, sleep

I used `DBMS_LOCK.sleep(50);` in the middle of the code.

However, when I run the PL/SQL code. It looks like it is running the 'DBMS_LOCK.sleep` in the beginning instead of executing the code before the sleep code.

Please suggest some solution to add about 50 seconds of delay in the PL/SQL code.

Comment: **[How to get dbms_output to print line before the end of the procedure?](https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2018/03/how-to-get-dbms_output-to-print-line-before-the-end-of-the-procedure.html)**

Comment: I figured it out myself. I did not have `commit;` code after `insert` and `updates` so it was not inserting the rows till the end of the code.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you may be confusing "executing" with "output".  For example, if I do:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Line1');
  dbms_lock.sleep(30);
  dbms_output.put_line('Line2');
end;
```

then when run, I will see nothing for 30 seconds..and then see *both* lines come out at the end of the execution.  But the "Line 1" did indeed execute before the sleep - but we only *see* output at the end of the execution of a block.

We can easily demonstrate that by changing what we output

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('I ran at '||to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS'));
  3    dbms_lock.sleep(30);
  4    dbms_output.put_line('and I ran at '||to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS'));
  5  end;
  6  /
I ran at 10:49:54
and I ran at 10:50:24
```

Comment: If you intention is a bit more complicated like checking how much time is spend in each line of a package or procedure, you could use dbms_profiler.  check out this blog. https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2197231/Oracles-DBMSPROFILER-PLSQL-Performance-Tuning.htm

Comment: @Vijay Balebail : That comment doesn't belong here.

Comment: I have my code insert some rows into a table then wait for 50 seconds for table to do some process for the rows I inserted so after 50 seconds I can do more tasks. but it my code it waits 50 seconds for then inserts the rows then right away it will do the next task.